# & symbol not printing in bibliography or citation

Tags: biblatex

My bibtex code is:

```
@TechReport{MarlinJones2020,
  author      = {{Marlin P. Jones \& Assco. Inc.}},
  institution = {{Marlin P. Jones \& Assco. Inc.}},
  title       = {{HC-SR501 PIR MOTION DETECTOR}},
  year        = {2020},
  url         = {https://www.mpja.com/download/31227sc.pdf},
}
```

For some reason the '&' symbol is not printing and I am receiving the

```
Misplaced tab alignment character &....
```

error

Comment: Try `{\&}` or `\protect{\&}`. This are just guesses. **Make sure** that you delete all the automatically generated files (e. g. `.aux`) before you compile after you change something. They might include a "bad" character from the last run, even after you corrected the actual code.

Comment: `&` is a special char in latex, you when used as a text symbol you need to escape it `{\&}` ought to be enough.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ and whether you use biblatex or bibtex to create the formatted bibliography. If you use BibTeX, please also tell us which bibliography style is in use.

Comment: Alternatively, try `author = {Marlin P. Jones and Assco. Inc.},` or `author = {Marlin P. Jones and {Assco. Inc.}},` (the position of `{}` is modified compared to your code).

Comment: Thank you the {\&} solved my problem! I also had to delete all the generated files as you suggested for the error to disappear.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as having been solved with the help of the comments provided by various users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the next time, provide a so-called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) like I show here. This makes it easier to help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

% Generate a bib file "on the fly" for testing.
\begin{filecontents*}{myTestDatabase.bib}
@article{myRefKey01,
  author        = {Hans Wurst and Mueller, Andreas},
  title         = {Title {\&} Title},
  publisher     = {Jumper},
  year          = 2020,
  journaltitle  = {Journal Name},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{myTestDatabase}

\begin{document}

% Show all references without explicitely calling them
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

> **Make sure** that you delete all the automatically generated files (e. g.
>   .aux) before you compile after you change something. They might
>   include a "bad" character from the last run, even after you corrected
>   the actual code. See the **screenshot**, all the selected files can be deleted.

[image]

[`biblatex` `MWE` `minimal working example`]